# Quale verbo è "affolsero"? E cosa significa?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Si fece strage di agnellini da latte e di capretti, di conigli e di cacciagione, e le donne impastarono foccazzole, cavarono cavatelli, torsero ricchitedde, arricciarono scr’ppelle col miele e col vincotto, **affolsero** calzoncelli con la crema di ceci o la marmellata di amarene, come se Natale Carnevale e Pasqua fossero arrivati tutti insieme.

Non so quale verbo sia questo "affolsero" che appare nel brano sopra citato. Ho pensato fosse ["affoltare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/affoltare/), ma non ne sono per niente sicura. Me lo sapreste indicare?

Comment: Probabilmente una grafia strana per "avvolsero" (=avvolgere) nel senso in questo caso di "ricoprire"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Immagino che "affoltare" sia "affoltarono".

Comment: la 3a persona plurale del passato remoto di avvolgere è avvolsero

Comment: Sì, lo so, @RiccardoDeContardi.

Comment: Per curiosità: osservo che cercandolo con Google Books apparentemente vengono vari risultati, che però sono in genere occorrenze di “assolsero” mal scandite (evidentemente l'originale usava la “s” minuscola che somigliava un po' a una “f”). Ma non è il caso presente.

Comment: Eccetto [questo](https://books.google.es/books?id=pGb_ktHCsSwC&pg=PT28&dq=affolsero&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGqonwqKfoAhX06eAKHc_FAM4Q6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=affolsero&f=false), @DaG. ;)

Comment: Infatti, @Charo, il testo che citi non rientra in quello che dicevo. Era solo una curiosità!

Comment: Sì, lo so, @DaG.

Comment: I calzoncelli (piccoli calzoni) si avvolgono, naturalmente.

Comment: Sì, @egreg: ha perfettamente senso. Magari si tratta di qualche fenomeno fonologico tipico della zona.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: È scritto nella domanda: Mariolina Venezia. E la vicenda narrata nel romanzo ha luogo a Grottole (Basilicata).

Answer (score 4):

Il [*Della volgare elocuzione illustrata, ampliata, facilitata*](https://books.google.es/books?id=XBGdn1ewEfsC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22Della+volgare+elocuzione+illustrata,+ampliata,+facilitata%22+affoltato&source=bl&ots=cBvbGsrRp9&sig=ACfU3U0PfnO7E190lXqNHFqvqf4t2jT8Ew&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimyo2CubHoAhUaBGMBHauhC6cQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Della%20volgare%20elocuzione%20illustrata%2C%20ampliata%2C%20facilitata%22%20affoltato&f=false) (Bergantini, 1740) a pagina 158 riporta **ripieno** tra i significati affoltato e **pressare**, **premere** tra i significati di affoltare.
Vari dizionari collegano il verbo affoltare con concetti relativi a premere, comprimere, stringere insieme, affollare.

Mi sembra strano che *affolsero* sia un refuso di avvolsero.
Credo invece che vada inteso nel senso di **riempirono**, come variante di *affoltarono*.
Mi sembra anche piú appropriato al contesto che i calzoncelli si riempiano con crema o marmellata, non che vi si avvolgano.
Non sono calzoni e calzoncelli solitamente delle paste (dolci o salate) ripiene?